# Keep Pivot Bar after navigate

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

In iOS I got this ->    Window -> TabbarController -> NavigationController -> ViewController

The Tabbar is always on the bottom. If I push a new ViewController to the navigationController the Tabbar is still shown.

On Windows Phone there is the Pivot. The Title Bar is like the Tabbar on ios and the pivotitem is like a viewController.  But how can i change the pivotitem and keep the Pivot... with NavigationService i exchange the whole xaml. but i only want to change a pivot item... maby with slide animation.

Comment: Just because the convention is to do it like that on iOS, doesn't mean that it should be done like that on Windows Phone (or other mobile platforms, for that matter) - I'd recommend reading Artuo's [blog post on the Hub & Spoke model](http://ux.artu.tv/?p=220) to better understand your user's expectations on how the app will work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand =)
Slide animation in Pivot is a default way to change current PivotItem. You just slide the screen with your finger and PivotItem changes to another

```
<Pivot>
  <PivotItem />
  <PivotItem />
</Pivot>
```

Comment: not from one privotitem to another.... i want to change the content inside of one privotitem... e.g.  the privotItem is a array/stack of views... and i can switch them.... but on the same category of the pivot topbar